# Массив php - сортировка с заданным порядком элементов

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => qwerty-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => qwerty-2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data] => qwerty-3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [data] => qwerty-4
        )
)
```

Нужно отсортировать его с использованием сортирующего масссива (задать порядок элементов)

```
$order_arr = [3, 1, 2, 0]; // порядок элементов

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => qwerty-4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => qwerty-2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data] => qwerty-3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [data] => qwerty-0
        )
)
```

Comment: в Вашем коде (результате) вместо `qwerty-0` должен быть `qwerty-1`

Comment: а вам его реально надо отсортировать, или просто вывести в этом порядке?

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [
    ['data' => 'qwerty-1'],
    ['data' => 'qwerty-2'],
    ['data' => 'qwerty-3'],
    ['data' => 'qwerty-4']
];

$order_arr = [3, 1, 2, 0];

$arrSorted = [];

foreach ($order_arr as $idx) {
    $arrSorted[] = $arr[$idx];
}

// print_r($arrSorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

Не создавая новый массив:

```
$order_arr = [3, 1, 2, 0];
$array = [11,22,33,44];

$temp = [];
foreach ($order_arr as $key => $value) {
    // Используйте это условие если ожидается, что элементов на своих местах
    // больше, чем элементов, которые надо поменять местами
    // if (($key != $value) && !isset($temp[$value])) {
    if (!isset($temp[$value])) {
        // PHP 7.1++
        // [$array[$key], $array[$value]] = [$array[$value], $array[$key]];
        // $temp[$key] = TRUE;
        // PHP 7.1--
        list($array[$key],$array[$value]) = array($array[$value],$array[$key]);
        $temp[$key] = TRUE;
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```

---

**Маленькая рецензия:**

**1)** *Предложенный мною способ:* самый быстрый и требует среднее количество памяти;

**2)** [Способ предложенный Kirill Korushkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/961974/3967): чуть дольше выполняться будет и чуть больше памяти (за счет создания нового массива);

**3)** [Способ предложенный Alex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/961976/3967): будет самым долгим, но меньше всего брать памяти.

**P.S.** Если объемы массивов не большие - берите любой способ, который вам визуально нравится, если массивы большие, то об оптимизации стоит задуматься, выбирайте то, что вам ближе.

Comment: Он станет еще быстрее если `$temp[$key] = 1;` и `in_array` заменить на `empty/isset`.

Comment: @u_mulder idealno

Comment: @Alex я это учитывал, все равно будет долгим за счет вызова анонимной функции каждый раз.

Comment: @Manitikyl да, и по скорости(рецензия) все верно (в прошлый раз тест показал скорость лучше 1 варианта, но это скорее случайность)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sort = [3, 1, 2, 0];
$array = array(
    0=>array('data'=>'qwerty-1'),
    1=>array('data'=>'qwerty-2'),
    2=>array('data'=>'qwerty-3'),
    3=>array('data'=>'qwerty-4')
);
$sort = array_flip($sort);
```

*Вариант 1 (с сохранением ключей):*

```
uksort($array, function($a, $b) use ($sort) {
    return $sort[$a] > $sort[$b];
});
```

[Тест варианта 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/895cfd68469f618a7aaffa1907873f84a6802ff4)

*Вариант 2 (без сохранения ключей):*

```
uksort($array, function($a, $b) use ($sort) {
    return $sort[$a] > $sort[$b];
});
$array = array_values($array);
```

[Тест варианта 2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5bd95eccc7b1fb37f7e49a7f20c314b1ba688a8)

Comment: Не лучше-ли `$sort = array_flip($sort);` вынести за пределы функции?

Comment: @Manitikyl в принципе да, можно ее вынести, чтобы не вызывать `array_flip` каждый раз, спасибо)